# Why is googlebot requesting robots.txt from my SSH server?

Tags: ssh, web-crawler, robots.txt, googlebot

I run ossec on my server and periodically I receive a warning like this:

```
Received From: myserver->/var/log/auth.log
Rule: 5701 fired (level 8) -> "Possible attack on the ssh server (or version gathering)."
Portion of the log(s):

Nov 19 14:26:33 myserver sshd[2105]: Bad protocol version identification 'GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1' from 66.249.73.226
```

The IP address always corresponds to a google crawler.  But why in the world would googlebot be trying to index my SSH server?  We run SSH on the standard, well-known port (22), so it seems like google would know better than to look for a web server there.  And we definitely haven't published any links that would lead it to believe otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Have you searched google for `<Your IP>:22`?  I'm sure you haven't published it anywhere as you say, but any old idiot can put up a link to anywhere that googlebot can notice.  Have you had this IP block for a while?

It seems much less likely, though not impossible, that Google is starting to do something about the 'dark web' that they've talked about before (searching commonly non-firewalled ports for stealth webservers).

There's a no-useful-answer [question](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/rnf8TSBTGOQ) on Google's forum from a couple years ago where somebody was seeing it on their mail server:

Comment: I've searched for every hostname/address that resolve to this host, but no results.